# regex lazy capturing fails after lazy "anything" ... unless I know what follows

Tags: php, regex, lazy-evaluation, pcre

In my PCRE engine (and on regex101) I can use this regex:

```
abc [\s\S]*?(mno)?
```

run against this string

```
abc random mno unknowable
```

it does not return the `mno` ... unless I add to the end of the regex, like so:

```
abc [\s\S]*?(mno)? un
```

Please note that I have simplified the regex to show the problem ... but this comes from a "real life" regex interpreting extracted text from a business document.  The key point is that there must be some text (the abc) otherwise the regex must fail ... then there can be some more text and an optional `mno` ... but it is impossible to guess the "random" or the "unknowable" in-between and following.

The solution has eluded me over several days of trying.  I'm hoping smarter people than me will know the answer.

Comment: So you want to match until and including the first occurrence of "mno" if it exists, and the whole string if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Or do you want it to just match the `abc` part if no "mno" exist?

Comment: Hey @Sweeper ... if there is no `abc` then the whole regex must fail.  If there is an `abc` the regex will return subpatterns that are within `abc` ... and also (if it exists) `mno`.  @HaoWu has an answer (below) ... which has (I think) led me to the correct answer ... which is `abc (?:[\s\S]*?(mno))?` ... so do the capturing of the "random" within an optional capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to capture an optional text `mno` from a pattern.

If so, you can try using a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!mno)` to make sure `[\s\S]` won't consume the text you are looking for `mno` accidentally while in greedy mode.

In fact, you should not use non-greedy mode while the text you want to capture is optional - it'll simply not match anything.

Here's a working solution:

```
abc (?:(?!mno)[\s\S])*(mno)?
```

See [the proof](https://regex101.com/r/xJE0c2/1).

---

#### Edit

If `mno` is a complicated pattern, you can still find the optional `mno`.
But this time, instead of `mno`, you should exclude the certain part `abc`  for the negative lookahead, so it won't cross another `abc`  section while searching for the complicated pattern `mno`

Notice the `?` quantifier is on the whole thing that contains `mno`, not `mno` itself:

```
abc (?:(?:(?!abc )[\s\S])*(mno))?(?:(?!abc )[\s\S])*
```

This case it can still capture the complicated `mno`.

See [the proof](https://regex101.com/r/sebIKf/1)

Comment: Hi. Thank you.  That clearly works ... but the "mno" is ridiculously complex itself (I've edited the question to show this).  Your solution, though, has given me the idea for what might be the (very simple) answer ... which is this:  abc (?:[\s\S]*?(mno))?  ... what do you think ?

Comment: @MichaelHains I've updated the answer according to your clarification, please check